# Favslider plugin for Joomla not resizing images in IE or Firefox only in Google Chrome

Tags: css, joomla, joomla-extensions

I installed Favpromote plugin from here http://extensions.favthemes.com/favpromote , all is working ok but the image is not resized when I`m seeing my website in Mozilla or IE. I see the images resized only in Google Chrome and I don`t know what should be the problem. My website is http://elevatorserv.eu
The .css code for this plugin is this:

```
    #favpromote {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#favpromote:hover {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 400ms linear;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
}
#favpromote h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
#favpromote:hover h3#favpromote-title,
#favpromote:hover h3#favpromote-title a,
#favpromote:hover h3#favpromote-title i {
    background-color: #111!important;
    color: #fff!important;
}
#favpromote-text {
    padding: 4px 21px 14px;
    margin: 0;
}
#favpromote:hover #favpromote-text {
    color: #fff!important;
}
#favpromote-uploadimage {
    padding: 21px;
}
#favpromote-uploadimage img {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
#favpromote-uploadimage img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#favpromote #favpromote-title a {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#favpromote #favpromote-title a:hover {
    color: #fff!important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    #favpromote-uploadimage img {
        margin: 0 0 21px 0;
    }

}
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Is the image supposed to resize on lower screen resolutions? Can you please be more specific and provide an example, possibly a link to your website as it's impossible to tell what the problem is. Have you also tried contacting the developer of this extension?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I typed my website in the question. Yes, the images need to resize on lower screen rezolutions too and I see that on mobile is working ok too. And on PC is working as it should in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

Go to the following file:

**templates/favourite/css/joomla.css**, go to line ***1676*** and you will find the following:

```
.moduletable, div[class^="moduletable-"], div[class*=" moduletable-"] {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

`float:right;` is what is causing the problem. So to override this issue, simply add the following below which will not affact the language flags at the top:

```
#fav-bottom .moduletable, div[class^="moduletable-"], div[class*=" moduletable-"] {
    float: none;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I see, this is the problem but it was from my mistake, if I do that, my language chooser flags from right are moving to left.. if there a way I can move the flags to the right without breaking something else? Thank you again.

Comment: Hi again, I see that I installed another gallery plugin and I have the same problem with this one too on this page: http://www.elevatorserv.eu/portofoliu . Can someone help me to solve it please ? And if you can tell me how should I know what to find and where if it`s happening again. Thank you.

Comment: Solved id, added another line: #fav-intro1 .moduletable, div[class^="moduletable-"], div[class*=" moduletable-"] {
    float: none;
}